# NSCollectionView with Header and Footer

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xcode7, nscollectionview

I need something like this:

[image]

But my code do this:

[image]

```
func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSView {
    let a = myView()
    if kind == NSCollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
        a.frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1000, 10)
    }
    else if kind == NSCollectionElementKindSectionFooter {
        a.frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1000, 12)
    }
    return a
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func numberOfItemsInSection(section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 5
    }
    else if section == 1 {
        return 5
    }
    return 10
}
```

The two headers and footers are in the position x=0,y=0, so how calculate the **y** position from my custom views (Header and Footer)?

Comment: Do you required horizontal scrolling or Fixed width?

Comment: @ArunAmmannaya Fixed width

Comment: Then this can be easily achieved using UITableview. UITableview is perfect for such requirement.

Comment: Are you using CollectionViewLayout for this?

Comment: @ArunAmmannaya _numberOfItemsInSection_ returns dynamics numbers (this code is an example).

Comment: Yes. Still we can achieve using UITableview. numberOfItemsInSection should return totalNumberOfItems/numberOfItemPerRow. If totalNumberOfItems items are not multiple of numberOfItemPerRow then last row of the section should hide extra items.

Comment: @HarryNg no, should I?

Comment: @ArunAmmannaya what about drag and drop? NSCollectionView makes that easiest, isn't it?

Comment: @Geek20 Header and Footer are provided in NSCollectionViewFlowLayout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Apple's sample project `CocoaSlideCollection`, section header and footer are available to `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout`, check out `AAPLBrowserWindowController` and `AAPLWrappedLayout` for more details.

To convert into Swift and English :P, the brief explanation is as below:

1. Implements the protocol `NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`
2. Implements the two methods `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` and `referenceSizeForFooterInSection`
3. `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` will be called after step 2

For step 3, I use the following code

```
func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSView {
    var nibName: String?
    if kind == NSCollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
        nibName = "Header"
    } else if kind == NSCollectionElementKindSectionFooter {
        nibName = "Footer"
    }
    let view = collectionView.makeSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withIdentifier: nibName!, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    return view
}
```

The identifier `nibName` used here, links to the two nib files I created to set the NSView, namely `Header.xib` and `Footer.xib`

This is the result collectionView I get.

[image: NSCollectionView with Header and Footer]

Hope it helps, I am creating a video tutorial for this. Help it helps.

Edit 1:

[Sample Code](https://github.com/harryworld/NSCollectionView-Header-Footer) is now available

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should check two things

First is click your **collection view attributes inspector**

you can see check two check box like this

accessories * section Header, section Footer

Second is **override** keyword

I guess you should put override keyword in front of your func keyword!

Comment: Indeed; why `override`? He is just implementing a function in the protocol. The compiler should complain that it is not an override method.

Comment: Are you sure about the _section Header, section Footer_? because I don't see them. _Xcode 7.2_

Comment: @NicolasMiari oh, i don't know about it, if it is protocol, that's not problem!

Comment: @Geek20 if you click empty area in collection view storyboard, you can see accessories section in attribute inspector. It is available in Xcode 7.2

Comment: @lucy is right. The attributes inspector looks waaay different for OSX apps vs. iOS apps. There is no "Accessories" checkbox group.

Comment: But there is "Header Size" and "Footer Size". Make sure they're not 0.

Comment: @NicolasMiari I set Header Size and Footer Size values but it doesn't work.